# Помогите написать регулярное выражение для поиска тега

Tags: html

Здравствуйте!
Помогите составить регулярное выражение для поиска тега  и всего его содержимого. 
Вариант .* не подходит т.к. html код разбит на несколько строк. Ниже привожу примерный html код, который нужно найти:

```html
<span class="consumption">
            здесь какой-нибудь текст... 
            <i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
```

Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Парсить HTML регулярными выражениями вредно для здоровья.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5232946

Comment: @andreymal а как тогда предлагаете решать задачу?

Comment: Взять любой полноценный парсер HTML, благо для любого языка программирования их навалом на любой вкус

Comment: результат должен быть именно этот блок? или только его текст?

Comment: не указан язык програмирования для решения задачи. Нет метки regex что означает складировать вопрос в раздел с регулярными выражениями

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, на `php`, можно так

```
if (preg_match('~class="consumption">([^<]*)~', $html, $match)) {
    echo $match[1];
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Известный баян, иллюстрирующий всю бессмысленность использования регулярок с HTML: https://habrahabr.ru/post/175179/#comment_6086921 
Более научное рассмотрение вопроса: https://habrahabr.ru/post/171667/ 
Но как вам уже написали в комментариях - выкиньте регулярки. Всё равно описать регуляркой все мыслимые варианты не получится. Всегда будет что-то что её сломает. Просто возьмите специализированный HTML или XML парсер.

Comment: Добавьте краткую выжимку к ссылкам, так как просто ответы-ссылки здесь не приветствуют.